# fitness cost calculation finding the weighted sum

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am having a little bit of trouble making a weighted sum calculation for subpaths(Where subpath is the path between two cities e.g. A->B) in a travelling salesman problem.

Basically I have 3 variables 'Fitness', 'Distance'(distance of the subpath e.g. A->B) and 'OverallDistance' (distance of the complete path A->B->D->C->E). I want to find the 'OverallFitness' of the subpath using a weighted sum.

** I want to make it so that variables with higher 'OverallDistance' value have a Lower 'OverallFitness' value. <- I believe this is achieved by calculating the inverse of the distance?

FITNESS_WEIGHT = 0.6

DISTANCE_WEIGHT = 0.4

AverageFitness = 120

Distance = 600

OverallDistance = 3600

// This is what I am doing:

double citiesVisited = citiesInTour/totalNumOfCities;

double distance = tourDistance/totalNumOfIndividuals;

double fitness = ((VISITED_WEIGHT * citiesVisited) + (DISTANCE_WEIGHT * distance));

I believe both the citiesVisited and the distance is normalised like this? Does this look right?

Many thanks.